# How do I determine the portal row number?

Tags: filemaker

How do I determine the portal row number when dragging a document into a container field in FileMaker? Dragging a document into a container field doesn't change focus, so `Get(ActivePortalRowNumber)` doesn't work.

Comment: You may be able to make a work-around using the `OnObjectModify` script trigger: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7465

Comment: I think you may have to force users to click a button in the row (could be the container field itself which would in this case be set not to allow editing), which would take the user to another layout that would permit dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could have a second relationship to the same related records sorted by the modification dates of the related records, most recent first. Then the record that had had the document dragged into the container field would appear as the first related record via that relationship, and you could grab an ID field from it.

Alternatively, each related record in the portal could contain an unstored calculation field set to "get(recordnumber)". Within a portal, that will evaluate to the portal row number of the record. Maybe you could use that somehow. Without more information on what you're trying to accomplish, though, it's tough to say.